# Grails 3.2.0 gets exception when running with gradle 3.2

Tags: java, grails, gradle

Hellow i am trying grails 3.2.0 with gradle 3.2. I am upgrading the application from grails 2.4.4 to grails 3.2.0. While using command run-app i got the below exception. There is no any indications of exact reason for the project.

See the below complete exception. I run command with stacktrace, debug and info.

| Running application...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.getTargetClass(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Class;
        at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.resolveDeclaredEventType(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.supportsEvent(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:280)
        at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:214)
        at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:62)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.started(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:363)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at myaccountgrailsupgrade.Application.main(Application.groovy:15)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.

  > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:61)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:45)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:233)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:74)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:55)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
      at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
      at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:197)
      at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:194)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:36)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:118)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:66)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:52)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:40)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:139)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:115)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.getModel(DefaultConnection.java:188)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableModelBuilderBackedModelProducer.produceModel(CancellableModelBuilderBackedModelProducer.java:54)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.PluginClasspathInjectionSupportedCheckModelProducer.produceModel(PluginClasspathInjectionSupportedCheckModelProducer.java:41)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:60)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher$1.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:89)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher$1.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:83)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:79)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
  Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
      at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
      at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:31)
      at org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.exec(JavaExec.java:74)
      at org.springframework.boot.gradle.run.BootRunTask.exec(BootRunTask.java:62)
      at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:624)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:607)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
      ... 64 more

| Error Failed to start server (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.2-bin.zip'.
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at java_util_concurrent_Future$get.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
        at run-app.run(run-app.groovy:89)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.script.GroovyScriptCommand.handle(GroovyScriptCommand.groovy:152)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.handleCommand(AbstractProfile.groovy:457)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:377)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:350)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:271)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.2-bin.zip'.
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:77)
        at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil$_runBuildWithConsoleOutput_closure3.doCall(GradleUtil.groovy:80)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
        at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil$_withProjectConnection_closure1.doCall(GradleUtil.groovy:61)
        at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil$_withProjectConnection_closure1.call(GradleUtil.groovy)
        at grails.io.support.SystemOutErrCapturer.withNullOutput(SystemOutErrCapturer.groovy:64)
        at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil.withProjectConnection(GradleUtil.groovy:60)
        at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil.runBuildWithConsoleOutput(GradleUtil.groovy:75)
        at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleInvoker.invokeMethod(GradleInvoker.groovy:50)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:929)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:906)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:168)
        at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleAsyncInvoker$_invokeMethod_closure2.doCall(GradleAsyncInvoker.groovy:57)
        at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleAsyncInvoker$_invokeMethod_closure2.doCall(GradleAsyncInvoker.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:495)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
        at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
        at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:121)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:66)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:40)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:139)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:115)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.getModel(DefaultConnection.java:188)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableModelBuilderBackedModelProducer.produceModel(CancellableModelBuilderBackedModelProducer.java:54)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.PluginClasspathInjectionSupportedCheckModelProducer.produceModel(PluginClasspathInjectionSupportedCheckModelProducer.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:60)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher$1.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:89)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher$1.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:83)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:233)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:55)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:194)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:36)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:118)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.exec(JavaExec.java:74)
        at org.springframework.boot.gradle.run.BootRunTask.exec(BootRunTask.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:624)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:607)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
        ... 64 more
| Error Failed to start server

D:\J2_Branch_Projects\grails-3.0\myaccountgrailsupgrade>

Comment: Try gradle 3.0. That is the version the wrapper uses

Comment: Grails 3.0 is a complete ground up rewrite of Grails and introduces new concepts and components for many parts of the framework. Check this documentation: http://docs.grails.org/3.0.x/guide/upgrading.html

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the migration instructions. Create a new 3.2 grails application and copy the domains and controllers...